# Creating a dropdown in HTML

Tags: html

I'm building a website for my fraternity (Phi Delta Theta) and I want to create a dropdown for one of my links and can't figure it out.

```
<!-- Nav -->
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul class="links">
            <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Our Mission.html">Our Mission</a></li>
            <li><a href="Join PDT.html">Join PDT</li>
                <div class="dropdown-container">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Future Phi Delt <a href="http://futurephidelt.org/"> </li>
                        <li>Parent's Guide <a href="http://www.phideltatheta.org/join/parents-guide/"> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS and HTML

Here is a snippet from https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

```
<style>
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like the below snippet: Hover over the link "Join PDT" to see the options, there are also various other options you can pick from, Good resource is W3Schools: [Dropdown examples](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp).I have used w3schools to prepare the snippet for you to look at below, hopefully it helps get you started.

```html
<html>
<style>

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

</style>
<body>

<!-- Nav -->
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul class="links">
            <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Our Mission.html">Our Mission</a></li>
          <div class="dropdown"><a href="Join PDT.html">Join PDT <b class="caret"></b></a>
 
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="http://futurephidelt.org/"> Future Phi Delt </a>
    <a href="http://www.phideltatheta.org/join/parents-guide/">Parent's Guide</a>
  </div>
</div>
            <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  
</body>
</html>
```